# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE" using NOT IN clause

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm creating a port scanner using python. When it finds an ip address I want it added to my "Devices" table.  However I need to check to make sure this same IP is not already in my tables from an earlier scan.  So I'm trying to run the following SQL in Python:

***cursorObj.execute("INSERT INTO Devices VALUES('"+ipAddrFound+"', null, null, null, null) WHERE '"+ipAddrFound+"' NOT IN (Select ipAddr from Devices)")***

However, when I run this I get the following error:
**sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error**

I'm not understanding what the problem is. Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Values` to `Select`

```
cursorObj.execute("INSERT INTO Devices SELECT '"+ipAddrFound+"', null, null, null, null WHERE '"+ipAddrFound+"' NOT IN (Select ipAddr from Devices)")
```